# Rename Elements In Pyspark Column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, rename

I'm currently trying to rename the elements in my pyspark dataframe. The dataframe df looks like this:

```
+--------+------+------+
|   hello|  this|column|
+--------+------+------+
|     132|   234|   abc|
|34563465|134134|   def|
|      12|    34|   ghi|
|     132|   234|   jkl|
|34563465|134134|   mno|
|      12|    34|   pqr|
|     132|   234|   stu|
|34563465|134134|   ghi|
|      12|    34|   pqr|
+--------+------+------+
```

What I am trying to do is rename every element in the 'column' column along the lines of this:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].map({'abc': 'cba',
                                 'def': 'fed',
                                 'ghi': 'ihg',
                                 'jkl': 'lkj',
                                 'mno': 'onm',
                                 'pqr': 'rqp',
                                 'stu': 'uts'})
```

So that the dataframe will then look like this:

```
+--------+------+------+
|   hello|  this|column|
+--------+------+------+
|     132|   234|   cba|
|34563465|134134|   fed|
|      12|    34|   ihg|
|     132|   234|   lkj|
|34563465|134134|   onm|
|      12|    34|   rqp|
|     132|   234|   uts|
|34563465|134134|   ihg|
|      12|    34|   rqp|
+--------+------+------+
```

How can I do this change in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `replace` function:

```py
mapping = {
    'abc': 'cba',
    'def': 'fed',
    'ghi': 'ihg',
    'jkl': 'lkj',
    'mno': 'onm',
    'pqr': 'rqp',
    'stu': 'uts'
}
df = df.replace(to_replace=mapping, subset=['column'])
```